# shadowMap cant detect all instances on THREE.InstancedBufferGeometry

Tags: three.js

I'm implementing something similar to the [buffer geometry instancing dynamic example](http://threejs.org/examples/#webgl_buffergeometry_instancing_dynamic).

Basically the idea is having one bufferGeometry duplicated and having an attribute array with the offsets of my objects (like they have in the above example).

If I try to add shadows, I only get shadows on 1 object, which I assume is because we only have 1 geometry.

Is there a way of adding shadows to all my objects?

```
var scene, camera, renderer, controls;
var offsets;

init();
animate();

function init() {

    scene = new THREE.Scene();

    camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(75, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 1, 10000);
    camera.position.set(0, 250, 1000);

    renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer();
    renderer.shadowMap.enabled = true
    renderer.shadowMap.type = THREE.PCFSoftShadowMap
    renderer.gammaInput = true
    renderer.gammaOutput = true
    renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
    document.body.appendChild(renderer.domElement);

    controls = new THREE.OrbitControls(camera, renderer.domElement);

    // Lights
    var ambient = new THREE.AmbientLight(0xcccccc);
    scene.add(ambient);

    var spot = new THREE.SpotLight(0x999999, 1, 0, Math.PI / 2, 1);
    spot.position.set(700, 700, 700)
    spot.target.position.set(0, 0, 0);
    spot.castShadow = true
    spot.angle = Math.PI / 4
    spot.penumbra = 0.05
    spot.decay = 2
    spot.distance = 10000
    spot.shadow.mapSize.width = 1024
    spot.shadow.mapSize.height = 1024
    spot.shadow.camera.near = 1
    spot.shadow.camera.far = 10000
    scene.add(spot);

    var spotHelper = new THREE.SpotLightHelper(spot)
    scene.add(spotHelper);

    // Floor
    var geometry = new THREE.PlaneGeometry(3000, 3000, 10, 10);
    var material = new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial({
        color: new THREE.Color(0x777777),
        shininess: 5
    });

    var ground = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, material);
    ground.rotation.x = -1.57;
    ground.receiveShadow = true;
    scene.add(ground);

    // instanced geometry
    var instances = 10;
    var geometry = new THREE.InstancedBufferGeometry();
    var icosahedron = new THREE.BufferGeometry().fromGeometry(new THREE.IcosahedronGeometry(200, 3));

    geometry.addAttribute('position', icosahedron.attributes.position);
    geometry.addAttribute('normal', icosahedron.attributes.normal);
    geometry.addAttribute('uv', icosahedron.attributes.uv);
    geometry.setIndex(icosahedron.index);

    offsets = new THREE.InstancedBufferAttribute(new Float32Array(instances * 3), 3, 1);

    var vector = new THREE.Vector3();
    for (var i = 0; i < offsets.count; i++) {
        var x = Math.random() * 1000 - 500;
        var y = Math.random() * 1000 - 500;
        var z = Math.random() * 1000 - 500;
        vector.set(x, y, z).normalize();
        offsets.setXYZ(i, x + vector.x * 5, y + vector.y * 5, z + vector.z * 5);
    }
    geometry.addAttribute('offset', offsets);
    var material = new THREE.ShaderMaterial({
        uniforms: {},
        vertexShader: document.getElementById('vertexShader').textContent,
        fragmentShader: document.getElementById('fragmentShader').textContent,
        side: THREE.DoubleSide,
    });

    var mesh = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, material);
    mesh.castShadow = true;
    mesh.receiveShadow = true;
    scene.add(mesh);
}

function animate() {
    requestAnimationFrame(animate);
    renderer.render(scene, camera);
}
```

Example [JsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/andrevenancio/hd4Lzwbj/)

Comment: Duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34205069/three-instancedbuffergeometry-and-shadows